# Memory Leak in c++ about matrix and operator overloading

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, neural-network

I have a nerual network that working but it have memory leak and it collapse 1 or 2 gb memory per each seconds;

```
matrix<Tn> r = inp; 
r = (**(LayersWeights + i) & r) + *(LayersBiases + i); // This line does memory leak
//         matrix           matrix     float
```

There are operators that i have overloaded;

```
matrix<T> operator&(const matrix<T>& other); // & for matrix dot product
matrix<T> operator+(const T& other);
```

And this it matrix class struct

```
template <typename T>
class matrix{
    T *data;
    int col;
    int row;
    int size;
    matrix(int col , int row){
        this->data = new T[col * row];
        this->col = col;
        this->row = row;
        this->size = col * row;
    }
```

I have tried to destructer but it gives error that u are trying to reach deleted pointer (i guess);

```
~matrix(){
     delete data;
//     delete [] this->data; //both of this didnt work
}
```

Comment: `T *data;`  -- Just use `std::vector<T> data;`, then most, if not all of the memory leaks will disappear.  Using `std::vector` will also mean you can get rid of the user-defined destructor, and the constructor would simply be: `matrix(int col , int row) : data(col * row)` without any call to `new[]`.

Comment: just for the record new [] => delete [].

Comment: As to *why* your current code has memory leaks, did you implement a user-defined copy constructor and a user-defined assignment operator?  If not, your class is in violation of the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).  Go to the **Managing resources** section of that link.  The code in that section is similar to yours, where the mistakes are explained.

Comment: If you did not implement the constructor `matrix(const matrix&)` and/or `matrix& operator=(const matrix&);`, then I will close this question as a duplicate of the rule of 3.  But regardless, you should switch to using `std::vector`, as that will remove the need to implement the user-defined copy constructor or operator=.  If you *did* implement the copy and assignment operators, then you need to post them.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Do it

Comment: i cant use vector in my project because i have used data like *(this->data + i) in almost everywhere. And also adding number one by one makes very slower my code. For second one i cant use new [] => delete [] easily because every iteration use some informations from older arrays. right now im trying to make a intelligent constructor cuz some of lines i need just copy data to another object but for other ones i need to delete old object and replace new one (im talking about = operator). Sorry for my delay

Comment: it seems to will work just need just a bit adjustment thx :).

Comment: @Cavemanbob *i have used data like *(this->data + i) in almost everywhere* -- Why do that when that is the same as `data[i]`?  *And also adding number one by one makes very slower my code* -- I have no idea what this means.  A `std::vector` is not slower than using `new[]`.  -- *For second one i cant use new [] => delete [] easily** -- That is because you went and used raw pointers instead of `std::vector`.  If you had used `std::vector` from the start, none of these issues would have happened.  You basically made the problem harder than it should have been.

Comment: i use *(data + i) format cuz i feel more comfortable  while i use 2d matrix or like i used thir project **(Layer + i)->pointer array.  also i dont like using vectors.  but u are right vectors makes easy the life.

Comment: btw while i do matrix& operator=(const matrix&); my delete function gives error, as i know cuz of trying to delete a pointer that already deleted. ''' void operator=(const matrix& other) {
  col = other.col;
  row = other.row;
  size = other.size;
                delete this->data; // gives error
  this->data = new T[other.size]; // this is necessary cuz a = 5x6 matrix and we have a = b(7,8); b is 7 x 8 matrix so we new and larger array
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
   *(this->data + i) = *(other.data + i);
  }
    } ''' should i share almost all codes that in my project ?

Comment: The question has been closed, but your issues is that you are not implementing the copy constructor and/or assignment operator correctly.  For one, the signature of the assignment operator should be `matrix& operator=(const matrix& other);` -- it should not be returning `void`.  Second, I suggest you implement the copy constructor first, then the destructor.  Last is the assignment operator, and it could easily be implemented by simply using `std::swap` calls.  See [copy and swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).

Comment: [Here is an example](https://godbolt.org/z/1rK73G98P).  I changed the assignment operator to have the parameter passed-by-value instead of a const reference.  The `main` function is what you should be testing your class with, as it copies and assigns.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie "Do it" - you did, thanks